# What is the locus of the center of a circle which touches externally two given circles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

1) What is the locus of the center of a circle which touches externally two given circles ?

2) What is the locus of the center of a circle which touches externally a given circle and a given straight line(two circles will lie in one side of the given straight line  ?

I have no idea how to encounter these problems. Can anyone give me a hint to proceed?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics) especially under the "examples in plane geometry" section. You should be able to take it from there using the links provided in the wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Supposing the centers are $O_1$ and $O_2$, we need $XO_1-XO_2=r_1-r_2$, which is a constant, so $X$ varies on a hyperbola.

2) In this case, we need that $\delta(X,l)=OX-r$, which is simply a parabola. (The line l is a translated version of the directrix)

Comment: I did not get your hint of the second one..Can you please write little more on it?@william122

Comment: So, the distance to the line is the radius, and the distance to the center is $r_0+r$ (where $r_0$ is the radius of the initial circle). So, if we move the line $r$ units perpendicularly, this gives $OX=\delta(X,l')$, which of course is just a parabola.

Comment: So for every new circle there is a line?

Comment: Sorry, in my original comment I meant $r_0$ units perpendicularly